# Is a finitely generated equivariant module always equivariantly finitely generated?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, group-actions, invariant-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Assume $R$ is noetherian. Let $G$ be a finite group acting on $R$ with the action on $\mathbb{C}$ trivial. Let $M$ be a $G$-equivariant $R$ module, i.e. there is a $G$-action on $M$ such that
$$
g(rm)=(gr)(gm).
$$

Now assume $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, i.e. there exists a surjective $R$-module homomorphism
$$
\phi: R^{n}\twoheadrightarrow M.
$$
Here we do not assume that $\phi$ is $G$-equivariant.

> > My question is: is $M$ also $G$-equivariantly finitely generated, i.e. can we find a $G$-equivariant surjective $R$-module homomorphism
> > $$
> > \tilde{\phi}: R^{\tilde{n}}\twoheadrightarrow M?
> > $$

Comment: I think that the question you might want to ask instead is whether $M$ is a finitely generated $R\langle G\rangle$-module (here by $R\langle G\rangle$ I mean the twisted group ring with the corresponding action of $G$ on $R$).

Comment: Take a finite set of generators $S$ for $M$. We may replace it with $GS$ and thus assume $GS=S$. Let $F$ be a free module with basis $S$. Then $F$ has a natural $G$ action and the surjective map from $F$ to $M$ is $G$ equivariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, although this has nothing to do with finiteness--the problem is that the images of *all* the equivariant homomorphisms $R\to M$ may not generate $M$.  To see this, note $1\in R$ is fixed by every element of $G$, so the image of any equivariant homomorphism $R\to M$ is generated by an element that is fixed by $G$.  But the elements of $M$ that are fixed by $G$ may not generate $M$.  For instance, let $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ with $G=S_2$ acting by swapping $x$ and $y$, and let $M=R/(x,y)$ with the nontrivial element of $G$ acting by multiplication by $-1$.  Then the only element of $M$ that is fixed by $G$ is $0$.

Comment: I am missing something here. If I take the free module with basis $e$ and action $e\mapsto  -e$ and send $e$ to $1$ in $M$, isn't it a $G$- eqivariant surjection?

Comment: I assumed that when OP asked for an equivariant homomorphism $\tilde{\phi}: R^{\tilde{n}}\twoheadrightarrow M$ they meant to use the action of $G$ on the domain given by the action of $G$ on $R$ on each coordinate.

Comment: I don't know. In general that is too restrictive.